# Background makes my H1 text dissappear

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set a fullscreen background for my page but when I do this, the `h1` text disappears.

HTML:

```
<div class="background"></div>
<div class="text">
<h1>Welcome</h1>
```

CSS for `h1`:

```
.text h1 {
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:15vw;
    color:white;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-family:BebasNeue Regular;
    letter-spacing:2vw;
}
```

CSS for background:

```
html, body {
height:100%;
margin:0;
}

.background {
background-image: url("../images/background.png");
height:100%; 
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}
```

How can I put the `h1` text on top of the background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```css
html, body {margin: 0; height: 100%}

.background {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/1600x900');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.background > h1 {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15vw;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: BebasNeue Regular;
  letter-spacing: 2vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <h1>Welcome</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use z-index CSS property.

> The z-index CSS property specifies the z-order of a positioned element and its descendants. When elements overlap, z-order determines which one covers the other. An element with a larger z-index generally covers an element with a lower one.

Here's a [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) to understand it.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged, please update your answer to include the relevant information from the link. Please see: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) "*Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.*"

Comment: Added a quote from the link. Hope that does it.
@FluffyKitten, are you a bot?

Comment: That should help! For future reference, link-only questions often get flagged and deleted so make sure to include an explanation so your answers don't get deleted :)

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead

html

```
<body>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
</body>
```

css

```
h1 {
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:15vw;
    color:white;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-family:BebasNeue Regular;
    letter-spacing:2vw;
}
body {

     background-image: url("../images/background.png");
}
```

Or you could just make the

```
z-index
```

of the h1

```
z-index: 1;
```

and the z-index of the image

```
z-index: 0;
```

Comment: Simply adding the z-index property is not enough, you also need to set the position of the elements to either relative, absolute or fixed, by default it's static.

Comment: Actually, you don't though you should declare the position the z-index will work despite the position.

Comment: Really, check again then.

Answer (score 0):

put the `h1` in `.background div`

```html
<style>
 .text h1 {
  margin:auto;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:15vw;
  color:white;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-family:BebasNeue Regular;
  letter-spacing:2vw;
 }
 .background {
  background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/300.png/09f/fff");
  height:100vh;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
 }
</style>
<div class="background">
 <div class="text">
  <h1>Welcome</h1>
 </div>
</div>
```